# How do I toggle on a view more for one component and toggle off the others onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle, show

I am using a React functional component with ternary to toggle a show more feature.  I would additionally like the following logic: if one of the toggles is true (showing more), then the others are false (not showing).  Right now, they just stack on top of each other unless you specifically click the button for each to "off" again.

This is them in initial state:

```
const [showFirst, setShowFirst] = useState(false)
const [showSecond, setShowSecond] = useState(false)
```

Here's the login in the render to show one of the 'show mores':

```
  <button
     className="btn-show"
     onClick={() => setShowFirst(!showFirst)}>
     <p className="proj-name">86 List</p>
  </button>
```

Here's how it displays in its proper place:

```
{showFirst ? (
            <div className="hide-me">
              <p className="proj-lang">Built with: React.js, Ruby on Rails, Postgresql, CSS</p>
              <p className="proj-desc">86List is a community for service-industry professionals to talk about the clients that they serve. Built with Ruby on Rails and React.js, 86List requires login authentication and registration in order to view and interact with co-workers' posts. In future iterations, I want to allow users to create their own accounts and request to be a part of a community with a community leader's approval.</p>
              <img className="proj-img" src="/assets/86list.png" alt="" />
              <div className="proj-link-container">
                <a className="proj-link" href="https://github.com/aawferris/86list" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" alt="this repo's github">REPO</a>
                <a className="proj-link" href="https://86list.netlify.app/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" alt="live site for this link">SITE</a>
            </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
              <div></div>
          )}
```

I have tried making a handleClick that would toggle each back to false and the current one true, but it didn't work. Here's an example:

```
const handleFirst = () => {
   setShowFirst(!showFirst)
   setShowSecond(showSecond)
}

Thanks in advance!

Andy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Idea would be to have an array of objects where you have an attribute like
`showMore: true/false` and also some sort of an id like `id: 1`. Each time one of the buttons is clicked, you iterate over the array (which should be a state in the parent component), you set the `showMore` attribute of that clicked button to `true` and set all the other ones to `false`. Then you just set that array as your new State.